# Export a python dataframe from Google AI Platform Notebook to a table in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I got a dataframe in Google AI Platform Notebook (PN) that i would like to transfer to a table in Google BigQuery.

I am aware of the option to use: df.to_gqb() but that requires a pip install of pandas_gbq. I prefer to avoid pip installs on top of the libraries already included in PN to keep the setup as simple as possible.

Do i perhaps miss an easy solution?

Br, Torben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a native library for importing data into BigQuery, via the BigQuery Client Library.

As the "google.cloud" library is already part of AI Platform notebooks environment, you won't need to install any new packages (thanks Torben for the confirmation!)

Here is a link to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

Comment: Thanks! 
Works like a charm and no pip install needed as the "google.cloud" library is already part of AI Platform notebooks environment.

Comment: I found this short guide useful for BigQuery Client Library: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration